# Python SyntaxError : Read an integer N . For all non-negative integers i<N , print i2

Tags: python-3.x

Task: Read an integer N . For all non-negative integers `i<N` , print i2.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
if (n<=0) and (n>=20):
    print("Exit")
else:
    for(i=0,i<=n,i++):
        print(i*i)
```

I am getting below error

```
  File "solution.py", line 6
    for(i=0,i<=n,i++):
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Exit Status

255
```

Comment: I suggest you go to [the (excellent) Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) and start from the very beginning with the tutorial. Python have never had a C-like loop like the one you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the syntax from other languages, not from python.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
if (n<=0) and (n>=20):
    print("Exit")
else:
    for i in range(0,n):
        print(i*i)
```

Comment: Thank you jalazbe